# react-beautiful-dnd: height doesnt fit to content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, trello, react-beautiful-dnd

First of all i want to start of with the 2 files that matter most

**Board.js**

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { useDraggable } from 'react-use-draggable-scroll'
import { sidebar } from 'react-admin'
import { Box, Card, CardContent, CardHeader, IconButton, Typography, List, ListItem, Divider} from '@mui/material'
import {  MoreHoriz, Add, Settings, ViewColumnOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import useContextMenu from '../../components/hooks/contextmenu'
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'
import { BoardColumn } from './items'

const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
  
    return result;
};

const useBoardStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    board: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',

    }
}))

const createFakeData = (count) => {
    const genItems = (columnId) => {
        return Array.from({length: Math.random() * 20}, (v, i) => {
            const id = i;
            return {
                id: `${columnId}:${id}`,
                text: `item ${id}`
            };
        })
    }

    const data = {
        columns: {},
        columnOrder: []
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const columnId = `column-${i}`;
        data.columns[columnId] = {
            id: columnId,
            title: `Column ${i}`,
            items: genItems(columnId)
        }
        data.columnOrder.push(columnId);
    }
    
    console.log(data)

    return data
}

const initialData = {
    columns: {
        "column-0": {
            id: 'column-0',
            title: 'To do',
            items: [
                {
                    id: 'id:1.1',
                    text: 'Create board'
                },
                {
                    id: 'id:1.2',
                    text: 'Create board'
                },
                {
                    id: 'id:1.3',
                    text: 'Create board'
                }
            ]
        },
        "column-1": {
            id: 'column-1',
            title: 'Doing',
            items: [
                {
                    id: 'id:2.1',
                    text: 'Doing board'
                }
            ]
        },
        "column-2": {
            id: 'column-2',
            title: 'Done',
            items: [
                {
                    id: 'id:3.1',
                    text: 'Done board'
                },
                {
                    id: 'id:3.2',
                    text: 'Done board'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    columnOrder: ['column-0', 'column-1', 'column-2']
}

const Board = () => {
    const ref = useRef(); 
    const { events } = useDraggable(ref)  
    const classes = useBoardStyles();    
    const [board, setBoard] = useState(createFakeData(5))
    console.log()

    const {anchor, show} = useContextMenu(ref.current)

    const onDragEnd = (result) => {
        if(!result.destination) {
            return;
        }

        if(result.type === 'column') {
            
            const columnOrder = reorder(board.columnOrder, result.source.index, result.destination.index)
            setBoard({
                ...board,
                columnOrder
            })
        }
        // reordering in same list
        if (result.source.droppableId === result.destination.droppableId) {
            const column = board.columns[result.source.droppableId];
            console.log(result.source.droppableId)
            const items = reorder(column.items, result.source.index, result.destination.index);

            // updating column entry
            const newState = {
                ...board,
                columns: {
                    ...board.columns,
                    [column.id]: {
                        ...column,
                        items
                    }
                }
            };
            setBoard(newState);
            return;
        }

        // moving between lists
        const sourceColumn = board.columns[result.source.droppableId];
        const destinationColumn = board.columns[result.destination.droppableId];
        const item = sourceColumn.items[result.source.index];

        // 1. remove item from source column
        const newSourceColumn = {
            ...sourceColumn,
            items: [...sourceColumn.items]
        };
        newSourceColumn.items.splice(result.source.index, 1);

        // 2. insert into destination column
        const newDestinationColumn = {
            ...destinationColumn,
            items: [...destinationColumn.items]
        };
        // in line modification of items
        newDestinationColumn.items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, item);

        const newState = {
            ...board,
            columns: {
                ...board.columns,
                [newSourceColumn.id]: newSourceColumn,
                [newDestinationColumn.id]: newDestinationColumn
            }
        };

        setBoard(newState);
    }

    return (  
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
            <Box
                className='w-100 h-100 m-0 bg-warning'
                
                ref={ref}
                {...events}
            >
                {/**
                 * Start Right click options
                 */}
                <List
                    sx={(theme) => ({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: anchor.x,
                        top: anchor.y,
                        visibility: (show ? 'visible' : 'hidden'),
                        bgcolor: 'white',
                        boxShadow: theme.shadows[2],
                        border: '1px solid',
                        borderColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
                        zIndex: theme.zIndex.speedDial
                    })}
                >
                    <ListItem
                        
                    >
                        <IconButton 
                            size='small'
                        >
                            <Add />Create board
                        </IconButton>
                    </ListItem>
                    <Divider />
                    <ListItem
                        
                    >
                        <IconButton 
                            size='small'
                        >
                            <Settings />Settings
                        </IconButton>
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
                {/**
                 * End Right click options
                 */}
                
                    
                <Droppable droppableId='droppableCards' type='column' direction='horizontal'>
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        
                        <div 
                            ref={provided.innerRef}                            
                            className={classes.board}
                            {...provided.droppableProps}
                        >
                                {board.columnOrder.map((columnId, index) => (
                                    <BoardColumn key={columnId} column={board.columns[columnId]} index={index} />
                                ))}
                                {provided.placeholder}
                            
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Droppable>
                
            </Box>  
        </DragDropContext>          
    )
}

export default Board
```

**BoardItems.js**

```
import { Card, CardContent, CardHeader } from "@mui/material"
import { Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd"
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import { Loading } from 'react-admin';
import {memo, useRef} from 'react'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    cardList: {
        flexGrow: 0,
        flexShrink: 10,
        background: theme.palette.warning.main,
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        overflowY: 'auto',
        "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
            width: '10px',
            
        },
        "&::-webkit-scrollbar-track": {
            boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 5px grey',
            borderRadius: '10px',
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark
        },
        "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
            background: theme.palette.primary.light,
            borderRadius: '10px',
        },
        
    },
    card: {
        maxHeight: `calc(100vh - ${theme.barHeight} - ${theme.spacing(8)}) !important`,
        display: 'flex',
        flexShrink: 20,
        flexBasis: 'auto',

        width: '15vw',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        margin: theme.spacing(2),
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
    },
    item: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
    }
}))

export const BoardItem = ({provided, item, style, isDragging}) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return (
        <div
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            className={classes.item}
        >
            {item.text}
        </div>
    )
}

export const BoardRow = memo(({item, index}) => {
    if (!item) return null;
    console.log(index)
    return (
        <Draggable draggableId={item.id} index={index} key={item.id}>
            {provided => (
                <BoardItem provided={provided} item={item}/>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    )
})

export const BoardColumn = memo(({column, index}) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return (
        <Draggable 
            draggableId={column.id}
            index={index}
            
        >
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                <Card
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    className={classes.card}
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    
                    style={{...provided.draggableProps.style}}
                >
                    <CardHeader title={column.title} {...provided.dragHandleProps} />
                    <BoardItemList column={column} index={index} />
                </Card>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    )
})

export const BoardItemList = memo(({column, index}) => {
    
    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <Droppable 
            droppableId={column.id} 
            // mode='virtual'
            // renderClone={(provided,snapshot, rubric) => (
            //     <BoardItem
            //         provided={provided}
            //         isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
            //         item={column.items[rubric.source.index]}
            //     />
            // )}
        >
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                <CardContent
                    className={classes.cardList}
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    {...provided.droppableProps}
                >
                    
                    {column.items.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <BoardRow key={index} index={index} item={item} />
                        )
                    })}
                    
                    {provided.placeholder}
                </CardContent>

            )}

        </Droppable>
    )
})
```

I have one big issue in my board.js, that is the fact that whenever i put display on flex and its flex direction on row in the function below, all the columns displayed on the board will not size to its content but size to the screen. (Preview below)

```
const useBoardStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    board: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'stretch'

    }
}))
```

When display is flex: https://gyazo.com/a01327cb938d448cd3a87121ffbd579f

When display is not flex: https://gyazo.com/47e41c717d4a21b63bfa5baa24c03efb

As you can see column 1 takes up the entire screen when display is flex, and when it is not it fits its content.

I've already tried putting flex-basis, flex-shrink, flex-grow all on 0, which has resulted into nothing.

If anyone knows what i could do to make the columns size fit the content, help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?